Ошибка в JSONToken
Имеется класс, который должен читать JSON файл и отдавать Словарь с Именем страницы и его URL, которые записаны в JSON. В итоге от выдает ошибку:

The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.

Я не могу понять как этот исправить и что за JSON token
    internal class ConfigParser
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetListPages(string fileName)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> listPage = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            try
            {
                string json = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
                List<PageInfo> pages = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<PageInfo>>(json);

                
                foreach (var page in pages)
                {
                    listPage[page.Name] = page.URL;
                }
                
            }
            catch (JsonException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ошибка в JSON");
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Ошибка в Чтение");
            }
            return listPage;
        }
    }

[
  {
    "Name": "HomePage",
    "URL": "https://store.steampowered.com/"
  },
  {
    "Name": "AboutPage",
    "URL": "https://store.steampowered.com/about/"
  }
]


В fileName передан путь не к тому файлу.

Нет, путь передается верно 100%

Точку остановки поставьте и посмотрите что в string json, говорит там не JSON, значит там не JSON, магии не бывает. Учитесь заниматься отладкой, это очень важный для программиста навык! Вангую, что у вас там лишний символ или еще что-то подобное из-за кривой кодировки или кривого составления JSON. В любом случае - отладка, это ваше все.
